# How to optimize $.find().first()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, find, findfirst

I need to retrieve the first element.

I do that with this code...

```
$(element).find('.x').first();
```

As much as I understand, that code...

1. Retrieves all elements from `element` that matched `.x`,
2. Removes unneeded elements;

Is there any better way to do it? Like `$.findOne()` or something?

Comment: @Konerak You tell me... I asked the question.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to optimize it? Is it taking a *long* time at present?

Comment: I believe its a small optimization... but if I have great place where to ask 'how-to'... why not to optimize it?

Comment: It's a super small optimization. Unless it's causing serious grief, I wouldn't worry about it at all :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per jQuery docs:

> Because :first is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :first cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. To achieve the best performance when using :first to select
>   elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then
>   use .filter(":first").

So rewriting your selector to:

```
$(element).find('.x').filter(":first")
```

or (this one will give you direct descendants only and will be faster than `.find`, unless you're looking for nested elements too)

```
$(element).children('.x').filter(":first")
```

should give you better results.

---

**Update** After valuable inputs from [kingjiv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/717383/kingjiv) and [patrick dw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113716/patrick-dw) (see comments),
it does seem that these two are faster than `.filter(':first')` contrary to what the doc claims.

```
$(element).find('.x').first();   // faster

$($(element).find('.x')[0]);     // fastest
```

Comment: +1, but I would use `.first()` instead of `.filter(":first")`.  I'm not sure why the documentation suggests `filter` instead, `.first` is faster.  (`.first` makes a bit more sense for readability too, but that may just be preference)

Comment: @kingjiv: `filter` takes advantage of native `querySelectorAll()` which provides performance boost. `first` is the plain old style of selection where you first get all elements and the return the first one. So I guess the boost comes from single step execution in case of filter vs. 2 or more in case of `first`.

Comment: But unless my jsperf is flawed (modified someone else's I found on google) it isn't faster.  Plus I'm not seeing the 2 steps, you already queried the elements, now `.first` just grabs the first one.  http://jsperf.com/jquery-select-first/2

Comment: @Mrchief: For the same reason jQuery can't take advantage of native code like `querySelectorAll()` when doing `.find('.x:first')`, it also can't when doing `.filter(':first')` (where I believe it tries to use a native `matchesSelector()`). It's because the selector isn't a valid CSS selector. And even though the selector is named `:first`, it is still run against *every* element in the set. The method `.first()` is just a wrapper for `.eq(0)`, which of course grabs the first element directly.

Comment: Hmmm... that is weird. Seems like `querySelectorAll` is not getting used in the test or maybe its not as fast as documented or we're missing something subtle.

Comment: @patrick dw: After looking at the jsperf and jQuery source code, `.first()` does seem to be better then `filter`. Let me update my answer.

Comment: @Mrchief: Have a look at my answer regarding `querySelector`. It is way faster.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have it real fast, you should use native browsers methods. Modern browsers support [`querySelector` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector):

```
var $result;
if(element.querySelector) {
    $result = $(element.querySelector('.x'));
}
else {
    $result = $(element).find('.x').first();
}
```

The usage is a bit limited, as it would only work if `element` is a single element and if the selector is a valid CSS selector. You could make a plugin out of it. But then, if you consider all cases, like multiple elements etc., there is probably no advantage anymore.

So again, if you have a very specific use case, this might be useful, if not, stick with jQuery.

**Update:** Turns out, making a plugin is still faster: [**jsPerf benchmark**](http://jsperf.com/jquery-select-first/3)

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.findOne = function(selector) {
        try {
            var element, i = 0, l = this.length;
            while(i < l && (element = this[i].querySelector(selector)) === null) {
                i++;
            }
            return $(element);
        }
        catch(e) {
            return this.find(selector).first();
        }
    };
}(jQuery));
```

How this works:

The plugin iterates over the selected DOM elements and calls `querySelector` on each of them. Once an element is found, the loop will terminate and return the found element. There are two reasons an exception could occur:

- The browsers does not support `querySelector`
- The selector is not a pure CSS selector

In both cases the plugin will fall back to use the normal jQuery method.

Comment: I wonder why the plugin version is faster than the direct call to `document.querySelector`.

Comment: @patrick: I wondered about that too, I thought maybe the plugin is totally failing (not doing anything, but I think it works ;)). My guess is that it is a bit more expensive to start searching at the root of the document. And FWIW,  there seems to be no difference in Chrome.

Comment: Yeah, that's the only thing I could think of too. Surprising since the plugin needs to make multiple calls. Maybe `document.body.querySelector` would perform better.

Comment: This is very nice! I also revised your test as `document.querySelector != $foo[0].querySelector`. If you look at [revised](http://jsperf.com/jquery-select-first/6) results, plugin version is way slower than direct access but still faster than jQuery ones. Wish I could upvote more!

Comment: @Mrchief: Thanks, although the adjustment is not necessarily better. The first `.foo` element does not have a `.selector` descendant. It don't understand why there is such a big difference between `document.querySelector....` and the plugin in FF compared to Chrome, but ok. Still interesting results :)

Comment: That was going to be my next question - Are they doing the same thing? `document.querySelector` works on a bigger scope, hence is bound to be slower than an element scope. This is true for any jQuery selector as well.

Comment: @Mrchief: Yes it works in a bigger scope and only through that produces the same result. As I use the method on individual elements, they work on a smaller scope and of course if you compare only a single call, the smaller the scope, the faster the method. But I'm  explicitly iterating over a set of nodes and this is still faster than making a single call to an internal method, and that is a bit surprising...

Answer (score 2):

As crazy as it seems, in every performance test I've seen, `.first()` has better performance than `:first`.

As most people are suggesting, it seems as though using `$(element).find(".x:first")` should have better performance.  However, in reality `.first` is faster.  I have not looked into the internals of jquery to figure out why.

http://jsperf.com/jquery-select-first

And apparently using `[0]` and then rewrapping in a jquery object is the fastest:

`$($(element).find(".x")[0])`

EDIT: See mrchief's answer for an explanation of why.  Apparently they have now added it to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This should be better

```
$(element).find('.x:first');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `:first` selector:

```
$(element).find('.x:first')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to write:

```
$('a:first');
```

What you're writing is "in 'element', find '.x' and return the first one". And that can be expressed like this

```
$('.x:first', element);
```

Answer (score 0):

how about using [first-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) pseudo class ? like

```
$(element).find('.x:first-child')
```

However it might generate issues if your structure is like

```
<div>
   <p></p>
</div>
<div>
   <p></p>
</div>
```

so actually it is not what you are looking for (if you mean general solution). Others mnetions :first and this seems to be the correct approach

Comment: That could return multiple elements.

Comment: @John: you are right about this! i have updated my answer to explain the downside of this approach and to stress it might be not the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your bottleneck is really the `.find()`, which searches all the descendants instead of just the immediate children.

On top of that, you're searching for a class `.x` (which uses a jQuery custom search)  instead of an ID or a tagname (which use native DOM methods).

I would use Mrchief's answer and then, if possible, fix those two bottlenecks to speed up your selector.

Answer (score 0):

That way is fine according to the jQuery documentation, or at least better than using `:first` selector.

You can try as alternatives `.filter(":first")` or get the first element using array accessor against the `.find()` result `[0]`.

Also, instead of `.find()` you can change it to:

```
$('.x', element)
```

To narrow the search to `.x` elements inside element, intead of searching the whole document.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the `$(element)` and `.find()` calls using a descendant selector; I'm unsure of the performance comparison:

```
$("#element .x").first().hide();
```